# Kill subprocess in python

Tags: python

In my python script, I need to start a shell with a process, and I like follows:

```
cmd = "x-terminal-emulator -e mytask"
self.task = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This opens up a terminal where the process runs.

This process keeps running continuously. At some point, I want to kill this process, I try doing it like follows:

```
if self.jlink != None:
    print "Stopping", str(self.task.pid)
    self.task.kill()
else:
    print "Process doesn't exist"
```

The problem is that even thought the Stoppping ... message is printed, the process isn't killed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe use `os.kill(self.task.pid, signal.SIGTERM)`?

Comment: Tried that, didn't work.

Comment: you are using windows or linux?

Comment: Linux. The pid saved in the task, is it from the x-term or mytask? Could I have to kill both?